# "Bundle" selenium application with browser?

Tags: windows, firefox, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

Basically I'm going to distribute my Selenium program to a number of clients for automation purposes.

Rather than asking every customer to have FireFox installed (and risking possibly incompatible versions) I would prefer if I could have FireFox (or whatever browser) packaged in my program directory (perhaps a portable version).

All my customers will be using Windows btw.

Anyone tried this or have any suggestions to how this could be accomplished?

**EDIT: I suppose I could use PhantomJS with selenium and just package my software with the phantomjs driver. That would not require any external browsers to work, would it?**

Comment: Please specify which OS/OSes you are considering your standalone Firefox should be distributed for.

Comment: @SamProtsenko
Sorry for not specifying that. Windows will be the only OS used.

Comment: I mean, edit your question and add this information to it explicitly. You may also want to add "windows" tag (keyword) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have also HTMLUnit headless browser option. Please note that it has own proprietary JavaScript rendering engine so need ensure that your test also will work with the "regular" browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-ui) and [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) for Windows. Your customers could download easily removable images with browsers (no need to clutter Windows with browser files) and run your test suite in multiple containers in parallel.